# "libquadmath.la' is not a valid libtool archive" when configuring OpenMPI with gfortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I am trying to configure my openmpi with fortran, gfortran,

this is how I have configured my mpi.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi/2.0.1 --enable-mpi-fortran --enable-mpi-cxx --enable-mpi-thread-multiple
```

I get this error at making stage.

> /usr/local/gnu_gcc/lib/../lib64/libquadmath.la' is not a valid libtool
>   archive

any solution ?

Comment: What are you trying to build? Have you tried a toy mpi problem?

Comment: Where did you get gfortran? Don't you just have the static runtime libraries? What is your OS. Whicch versions of software do you have?

Comment: BTW are you sure you really need --enable-mpi-thread-multiple? Most people don't and it harms performance.

Comment: @VladimirF : I do need mpi thread multiple, OS is ubuntu 16.04, compiler gcc 4.9.4, openmpi 2.0.1

Comment: And where did you get the gfortran from? Is it the default one?

Comment: @VladimirF: gfortran is from gnu 4.9.4

Comment: Obviously... So where did you download it? How did you install it?

Comment: @VladimirF: I built it from source, 
configure --prefix=/usr/local/gnu/4.9.4 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go

then I made links to my usr/bin from this address

Comment: @aaramoon There is a similar problem and its simple solution in [this](https://gnunet.org/faq-la-files) article.

Comment: I don't think it will help him. I suspect he has his paths or symlinks not set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the instruction in this article[1](https://gnunet.org/faq-la-files) to solve the problem,

1. I removed all the *.la files in my gcc lib64 folder,

> sudo rm -f *.la

2. I ran in the configure folder

> make distclean

3. configure and install again

Comment: similar problem building/installing clamav.  Exporting LDFLAGS and updating ld.conf didn't work for me.  So I sym linked the location it was looking at (/usr/llib64) to the real location in case this helps anyone having similar issue.